# \pause does not not work with \only

Tags: beamer, pause, text-only

Why does `\pause` do not work with `\only` in this code?

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
\xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\frame{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
\only<1>{
\begin{itemize}
  \item point1
    \pause
  \item point2
    \pause
  \item point3
    \pause
  \item point4
    \pause
  \item point5
\end{itemize}
}
\only<2>{
\begin{itemize}
  \item essai1
  \item essai2
  \item essai3
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
  a+b=c
\end{equation}
}
\only<3>{
\begin{equation}
  a+5=10
\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really surprising: what exactly are you expecting to happen with `\pause` inside an `\only` block?

Comment: @JosephWright, it is the first presentation that I do with beamer. So, surely, I have not a good experience with it. I am doing a research about this problem and it seems to use counter for \pause or like this. I is not so clearly.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

Using `\only` means that the material is not printed on any slides you don't specify. At the same time, `\pause` automatically spreads material across slides. Thus trying to combine the two means that most of the input won't be printed: it's excluded from the `\only` list but is not on the 'correct' slide due to `\pause`.

In the example given, it looks like you really have three separate frames, rather than wanting to print stuff 'only' one slide of a frame. That suggests:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{section1}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item point1
    \pause
    \item point2
    \pause
    \item point3
    \pause
    \item point4
    \pause
    \item point5
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item essai1
    \item essai2
    \item essai3
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = c
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
  \begin{equation}
    a + 5 = 10
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'd caution that even then you're likely to be overdoing `\pause`: experience suggests you should use animation very sparingly.