# How to force a figure to appear if it's preceded by \pause?

Tags: beamer, pause

I have a slide divided into two columns. The columns on the left contains a list of item that appear one at time whilst the columns on the right has a figure. To make the items appear one-by-one, I am using `\pause`. Nevertheless, since the image is placed in the code after the last `\pause`, it does not appear until the last item in the list has been called, which is not my intention. I want the figure to be there since the start of the slide and the items to appear one-by-one.

I have tried forcing the placement of the image with `[!htb]` but it doesn't exert any change. What can I do to make the image appear since the beginning?

My code now looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My title}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \pause \item Item 1
        \pause \item Item 2
        \pause \item Item 3
        \pause \item Item 4
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{My_figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\pause` command does exactly what it says: pauses the slide at that point. For any more complex set up you need to use the flexible overlay 'action' specs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My title}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See [Relative overlay specification in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer) and also [\pause does not not work with \only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145025/pause-does-not-not-work-with-only) for more on this.

---

By the way, note that `figure` is not required in `beamer` as there are no floats and as captions are *strongly* discouraged in talks.